# Touchable Opacity not responding in stack navigator screen - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm building a React Native app, it uses React Navigation. I use TouchableOpacity throughout the app, however, in a stack navigator screen, it doesn't seem to work at all. Touching the element doesn't change the opacity and the onpress function doesn't work. The screen itself displays fine and all other screens in my app have TouchableOpacity's that work fine.

Using button doesn't respond either, I'm thinking this is a react navigation issue potentially? There is no issues transitioning to the screen though?

Here is my screen;

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Button}  from 'react-native';

class RaceScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'rgba(30,30,30,0.98)'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => console.log('Hello')}>
                    <View style={{ margin:50, height:100, width: 200, backgroundColor:'red', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center' }}>
                        <Text style={{ color:'white' }}>
                            Go back
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Button title="Go back button" onPress = {() => console.log('Hello')}>
                </Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default RaceScreen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In the createStackNavigator method from react-navigation, transparentCard:true is a deprecated property and was causing the bug. I was using version 3 documentation on a version 4 package of react navigation.

Looking at there site, they have just released version 5 which is great!

A note to the less experienced developers like myself, making sure you're aware of the version of each package you are using is critical for some of these difficult bugs. Don't let it get you down though, react native is elite!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the `Touchable` components typically don't respond well to text children. You simply need to wrap it inside a `View`:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert}  from 'react-native';

export default class RaceScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'rgba(30,30,30,0.98)'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => console.log('Hello')}>
                    <View style={{ margin:50, height:100, width: 200, backgroundColor:'red', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center' }}>
                        <Text style={{ color:'white' }}>
                            Go back
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, makes sense to me but unfortunately, my 'Go back' TouchableOpacity is still unresposnsive